# typescript 2.0: parameters with default values

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Hell guys,

Here's another typescript 2.0 question (with strict null check mode enabled). So, if you define a function which has default values for all parameters:

```
(name = "Luis", age = 40)=>void
```

Then all parameters are considered optional, ie, it's as if we have the following signature:

```
(name?: string, age?: number) => void
```

Right? Now, what happens when we have this signature:

```
(name = "Luis", age: number ) => void
```

According to VS code, that signature is compatible with:

```
(name: string, age: string) => void
```

Now, if I activate the strict null check mode, shouldn't the following call produce an error:

```
doIt(undefined, 30);
```

It compiles ok, but if I'm not wrong, undefined will only get added automatically to the list of types of optional parameters. I haven't found any references to default initialized parameters.

So, if the previous call is ok, can someone point me to where I can find info about it in the official docs ?

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: What is the exact signature of `doIt()` that you think should cause the compile failure?

Comment: Hello Dan.

well, in my case, doIt would be something like this function doIt(name = "Luis", age: number) { .... }.

Comment: That explains why there was no compile time error, but I see that @basarat has already explained why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick note: You cannot specify defaults in just signatures e.g. the following is an error:

```
declare var foo: (name = "Luis", age = 40) => void; // ERROR: defaults only allowed in implementation
```

Continuing the following code:

```
var foo = (name = "Luis", age: number) => null;
foo(undefined, 123);
foo(null, 123); // ERROR
```

Shows that the `name` is compatible with `string` or `undefined`. The tooltip is wrong but the general analysis is correct.

Feel free to raise an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues